# Visualization using D3

Tags: visualization, javascript

I am new to D3 programming (any programming, for that matter). I have protein-protein interaction data in JSON format and csv format. I would like to use that data for network visualization.

Data attributes: Protein Name, Protein Group, Protein type, Protein Source Node, Protein Target Node

Can anyone suggest good network visualizations for such data. How does it work with hive plots?

Comment: I would recommend to split up your question in parts and narrow down on certain topics. If I understand your question correctly you are seeking to advise on (1) plotting protein data, (2) plotting data stored in `JSON` and `csv` format, (3) plotting in D3 and hive. Could you rephrase your question so that it narrows down on just a single question?

Answer (score 3):

Why dont you have a look at the following example?
http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/2066421

You can also find a fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/boatrokr/rk2s5/

Pay attention to the part where the links are defined.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this interactive chart gallery- [Visual Index](https://github.com/d3/d3/wiki/gallery) simple to use and works just fine with any type of data.

Apart from this you can also give a try to any of these examples.

- [D3 Network Graph](http://bl.ocks.org/jose187/4733747)
- [R Bloggers](https://www.r-bloggers.com/network-visualization-part-6-d3-and-r-networkd3/)

Hope it helps!